# Insert React env variable into HTML script tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, environment-variables

I am using React environment variables and I am looking to insert one in my `index.html` `<script>` tag.

Here is what I've tried to no avail:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + process.env.REACT_APP_PLACES_API + "&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: have you tried injecting the script tag with js because as per my thinking regular html code won't let you use node process code in it so you will have to inject the js before rendering other functionality of js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using create-react-app, you can update your script like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%REACT_APP_PLACES_API%&libraries=places"></script>
```

You can check it [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

src={`url${variable1}url`}